# How to make service running even if there is no activity running?

Tags: android

Is there any way to keep my background service running indefinitely even if there is no activity of application currently running ?

there is a requirement where user can use other application on the phone and he either closed all application's activities or he moved to other application so the activity of my application goes to pause or stop state so in this case service should not get destroy.

I am not sure how to make it possible because as of now what I observed is whenever I pressed the back button of the phone when I am the first activity of the application, application's service is also get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Remote Service which is not bound to an activity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Comment: Could you please share me the complete example, because when i made service as different process in manifest file and try to run the application, it throws java.lang.ClassCastException:android.os.BinderProxy error, so couldn't be able to understand what wrong I am doing.whenever i tried to retrieve the service in activity inside onServiceConnected() method , it throws the same error but when i remove android:process=":remote" tag from manifest file then it runs properly but service will get closed when all activities are closed. so pls help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

for making background service then in android we have to extends Service class same as we are extends Activity in our application. And when you are extends service in your class then it will works as Background service. Then it will run until you uninstall your application from mobile or you are stop this service manually from settings.

More details of [Service class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and [example of service](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html).